# The Juniper EX switch. Crontab jobs

Tags: cron, csh

did someone use crontab on juniper swith EX series? I would like to do restart httpd job, because I need to run this process with different config. 
I create some simple script with logging.

```
#!/bin/csh
echo 'Go...'
cp /jail/var/etc/httpd.conf_new /jail/var/etc/httpd.conf
echo 'changed'
set http_pid=`ps aux | grep 'httpd --config' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
echo 'Process PID: ' "$http_pid"
kill -9 "$http_pid"
```

Also I create a job in crontab

```
10 12 * * * csh /var/root/test.sh >> test.log
```

When I run proces from cmd then output is:

```
Go...
changed
Process PID: 3158
```

And everything is ok but when I run it from cron then it looks like that:

```
Go...
changed
Process PID:
```

I try to change(add) to the crontab line with:

```
SHELL=/bin/csh
PATH=...
```

but didn't work. Also I try to change line with job to something like below:

```
10 12 * * * /var/root/.profile; csh /var/root/test.sh >> test.log
10 12 * * * sh /var/root/.profile; csh /var/root/test.sh >> test.log
10 12 * * * (sh /var/root/.profile; csh /var/root/test.sh) >> test.log
```

Maybe you know what can I do more to run this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this over the weekend.  When the script is run via `crontab` using `@reboot`, the script runs before `httpd` is running, therefore there is no PID.  I put a `sleep 60` in my crontab line and the script delayed for 60 seconds, when it runs, httpd is up and running and has a PID.

Here is my Crontab:

```
@reboot sleep 60; sh /jail/var/etc/httpd_replace_config.sh > /jail/var/etc/httpd_replace_config.txt
```

Comment: This is the only solution to one of my problems. The second was the transfer result of ps to variable http_pid. I analyzed the actions in script step by step, it turned out that the query ps aux result is limited in string length only to 80 characters. My grep was not detect the looking string. I must to change the ps aux to ps -A (shorter version).